# Multi Processing the build of Microsoft Interface Definition Language (.idl)?

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, midl, incredibuild

I have a COM project (Visual Studio with Incredibuild) with 200 midl file that generate .h and .c.
The processing of this midl files are made with only one core at the beginning of the built.
It is very long and take practically the half of the build time.

Is it possible to multi process this part of the build ?

As I can see in FAQ of Incredibuild, it should be possible to distribute the MIDL step.
https://www.incredibuild.com/frequently-asked-questions-technical.html#q39

(I have already enable /MP and the compilation of .c/.c++ are well parallelly build.)

Comment: Hmm, IDL is the foundation upon which your House of COM is built.  You can't start putting up the walls until the foundation is laid first.  And, don't forget, the client code as well.  Any IDL change you make is a breaking change.  It should only ever be done *very* sparingly.  Or to put it another way, it is supposed to hurt :)

Comment: Yes I agree that the IDL have to be made before everything. But I am looking a way to build them parallely and not one by one on a single core.

Answer (score 0):

Up until recently, it wasn't possible to build IDL's in parallel. A pre-release version of IncrediBuild now enables parallel build of moc and midl.  Contact IncrediBuild support if you want to get a copy of this pre-release version. You can visit this page for further instructions: https://www.incredibuild.com/qt-moc-and-midl.html

Good luck,
Uria

(I work for IncrediBuild)